# TypeORM Friend Table

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I've having trouble creating a Friends table and establishing the relationship back to the User table.

```js
@Entity("user")
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column("int", { default: 0 })
  tokenVersion: number;

  @OneToMany(() => Friend, (friend) => friend.targetId)
  friends: Friend[];
```

This is what I've tried for the Friend table but it is clearly wrong.

```js
@Entity("friend")
export class Friend extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.id)
  sourceId: User

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.friends)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "friend" })
  targetId: User;
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I would really appreciate it.